# When to convert immutable data to native JS in react components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

So, I have a component that receives props, which are immutable objects (thru mapStateToProps). I then send them as props to child components where they are used and also sent to their children.

Something like this, where Comp1 is the connected component.

Comp1 -> Comp2 -> Comp3...

My question is, at some point I need to use toJS() to actually make use of data. Where do I do this? Should I toJS() all the data in the render function? Should I do it in Comp1 and send native JS objects as props?

Moreover, I used this tutorial

http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html#introducing-a-client-side-redux-store

Comment: I'd probably do it in Comp1 so I'd only have to remember to call `toJS()` in one place, instead of in all the child components.

Comment: @Jack as I argued on the comment I would keep it immutable as long as possible, ideally forever using the "get" and "set" methods. That way you maintain the benefits of using Immutable.js

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Abramov stated somewhere on a github issue to someone wondering the same question, it's up to you to choose where and when to `toJS()` your Immutable object. Redux makes no assumptions about it.

Maybe you'll get some better advices about this.

The tutorial you read is indeed an excellent walkthrough for Redux/Immutable/Universal app. If I remember correctly the author never deals with plain objects but uses ImmutableJS API to update app state.

Comment: I agree, I don't think you should ever need it to be a real JS object unless you're dealing with code you can't modify. Views shouldn't change the data so it's better practice to **keep it immutable as long as possible**

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use toJS() in the selector or in the container and convert back to immutable in the reducer.

Is your personal choice.
Just keep in mind that state it have always to be immutable and updating immutable things a lot of time is slower than update non immutable things.